# In Data Studio - Create a pie chart from several columns

Tags: looker-studio

So I have a database with 5 columns:

1. Project
2. Total budget
3. Authorized to assign
4. Assigned
5. Paid

Columns 3, 4 and 5 sum up the total budget; thus each is a part of the total.

I would like to create a pie chart showing the percentage in each step. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The pie-chart takes 1 dimension and 1 metric so you'll need to transform your data to have the labels in one dimension column and the values in a metric column for it to work in pie-chart format